# Single Sign On Between .Net And Java Apps

Tags: java, .net, iis, glassfish, single-sign-on

We have legacy applications written in asp and asp.net on IIS using form based authentication against the Database (Not AD).  We are writing a new Java app sitting on glassfish and we want a single sign-on solution to authenticate users so they can move seamlessly between the two without having to sign on again.

Are there any secure solutions to this problem?

Comment: What will be the flow? User will first visit the new Java web application or old ASP Application? This link has a generic idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_access_management#Architectures

Comment: How does your .NET app track user identity after login?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach in the long term is to decide on a SSO technology / implementation, and then *change the legacy applications* to use it.  I know that changing legacy apps can be painful, but provided it is practical you should do it.

---

**UPDATE**

You don't necessarily have to do a complete rewrite of your legacy apps. If you can identify an SSO tech which supports the legacy language too, you can maybe just get away with rewriting the login page and (maybe) access control and/or local account management.

Comment: Agreed.  And actually, we've decided to just rewrite the legacy apps into java to prevent this and a few other obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at spring security (if you're not opposed to using spring for your java app). They support dozens of solutions, probably whatever you're using for your ASP app. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Alternatively you could use apache shiro http://shiro.apache.org/ which also supports just about anything out there for security.

I'd advise looking to see if one of these supports what you are using already on your legacy app, it would probably be easier to make the java app support your existing security mechanism rather than trying to backport a new security layer into ASP.